# BoxGeometry not aligning with SphereGeometry properly

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I am trying to create spikes on earth(sphere geometry). Though everything works fines, but spikes dont align with globe. I want spike to align something like below image. But my spikes dont `lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0))` despite mentioned. Please help me out.

I purposefully mentioned code required for debugging. Let me know if you need more code for this. Below image is how i want my spikes to align with sphere.

[image]

But this is how it looks

[image]

My Main JS initialization file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Initializing Camera
  Influx.Camera = new Influx.Camera({
    fov: 60,
    aspectRatio: window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    near: 1,
    far: 1000,
    position: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 750
    }
  });

  //Initializing Scene
  Influx.Scene = new Influx.Scene();

  // Initializing renderer
  Influx.Renderer = new Influx.Renderer({
    clearColor: 0x000000,
    size: {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    }
  });

  Influx.Globe  = new Influx.Globe({
    radius: 300,
    width:  50,
    height: 50
  });

  //
  Influx.Stars  = new Influx.Stars({
    particleCount: 15000,
    particle: {
      color: 0xFFFFFF,
      size: 1
    }
  });

  Influx.moveTracker = new Influx.moveTracker();

  Influx.EventListener  = new Influx.EventListener();

  (function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
    controls.update();
  })();

  function render() {
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    group.rotation.y -= 0.001;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  };

});
```

Below is code responsible for generating spikes on Globe.

```
Influx.Spikes = function (lat, long) {

  // convert the positions from a lat, lon to a position on a sphere.
  var latLongToVector3 = function(lat, lon, RADIUS, heigth) {
    var phi   = (lat) * Math.PI/180,
        theta = (lon-180) * Math.PI/180;

    var x = -(RADIUS+heigth) * Math.cos(phi) * Math.cos(theta),
        y =  (RADIUS+heigth) * Math.sin(phi),
        z =  (RADIUS+heigth) * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta);

    return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
  };

  var geom        = new THREE.Geometry();
  var BoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 100, 1);

  //iterates through the data points and makes boxes with the coordinates
  var position = latLongToVector3(lat, long, 300, 2);

  var box = new THREE.Mesh( BoxGeometry );

  //each position axis needs to be set separately, otherwise the box
  //will instantiate at (0,0,0)
  box.position.x = position.x;
  box.position.y = position.y;
  box.position.z = position.z;

  box.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  box.updateMatrix();

  //merges the geometry to speed up rendering time, don't use THREE.GeometryUtils.merge because it's deprecated
  geom.merge(box.geometry, box.matrix);

  var total = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: getRandomColor(),
    morphTargets: true
  }));

  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  };

  //add boxes to the group
  group.add(total);
  scene.add(group);
};

Influx.Camera = function(params = {}) {

  if ( !$.isEmptyObject(params) ) {
    window.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(params.fov, params.aspectRatio, params.near, params.far);
    camera.position.set(params.position.x, params.position.y, params.position.z);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
  } else {
    console.log("Trouble with Initializing Camera");
    return;
  }

};
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, please can you explain better what you mean with: "but spikes dont align with globe". I see nothing wrong on the image. By the way, it looks cool!

Comment: hey @juagicre i edited my question with picture of how i am getting the spikes. Those are not getting aligned with sphere .. i.e. `lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)` is supposed to do the job

Answer (score 1):

Remember that lookAt takes a [direction vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_vector), you give to this method the vector (0, 0, 0), this is actually not a normalized direction vector. So you must calculate the direction:

> from your box position to the center of the sphere AND normalize it.

```
var dir = box.position.sub(world.position).normalize();
box.lookAt(dir);
```

And now just a set of code good conventions that may help you:

```
var BoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 100, 1);
```

Here I would rather use another var name for the box geometry, not to mix up with the "class" definition from THREE and to follow naming conventions:

```
var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 100, 1);
```

And here:

```
box.position.x = position.x;
box.position.y = position.y;
box.position.z = position.z;
```

You can just set:

```
box.position.copy(position);
```

Comment: hey juagicre, where are we using `var dir` in the code ?

Comment: box.lookAt(dir); instead of box.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));  I guess center of the sphere/world position is (0,0,0) but the lookAt method does not take a position but a direction vector so you have to do this operation. Maybe you have to negate the direction, just try it out ;)

Comment: i get same orientation .. if i remove `box.updateMatrix` i dont get the boxGeometry shown also

Comment: if you want to get help give some more feedback... what dir values are you getting? Does it change at all the box orientation? can you try removing the "box.updateMatrix();" and not to merge it? you can try also to set hardcoded values to the dir vector like (1,1,1).normalize(), at the end this is a direction the box should look at. check that the rotation of the box has changed after this. Last question, is box type object3d? because THREE.Mesh has not the method lookAt...

Comment: Having `  var dir = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1).normalize();
  box.lookAt(dir);` changed the orientation ... As mentioned in my question (code)  box type is `new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 100, 1);`  ..

Comment: Do you think its something with rendering ?

Comment: is not a rendering problem. 100% sure. in your code you have this: var box = new THREE.Mesh( BoxGeometry ); I suspect box IS NOT A THREE.BoxGeometry... if the unitary normalized vector changed the orientation it means you are getting really close to your target, now you need to know what orientation you really want...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121225/discussion-between-rahul-dess-and-juagicre).

Comment: Sorry Rahul, I cannot chat at the moment. At 19:00 (Vienna time) should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem, and I fixed it, the solution is: box.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)) must after box.scale.z = xxxx

Comment: what does `xxxx` in this case be ?